# How to add class to the next DIV and fade out the current with dynamic number of items - multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I was wondering if there was a way to create a scalable (mainly) CSS slideshow for text divs - no images.

I have this current HTML structure:

```html
<div class="mb-panel-container cf">
    <div class="mb-panel-section mb-slider">
        <div class="mb-panel active">
            <h1>1.1</h1>
            <p>slide 1.1</p>
            <p class="datetime"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-panel">
            <h1>1.2</h1>
            <p>slide 1.2</p>
            <p class="datetime"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-panel">
            <h1>1.3</h1>
            <p>slide 1.3</p>
            <p class="datetime"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-panel-section mb-slider">
        <div class="mb-panel active">
            <h1>2.1</h1>
            <p>slide 2.1</p>
            <p class="datetime"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-panel">
            <h1>2.2</h1>
            <p>slide 2.2</p>
            <p class="datetime"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-panel">
            <h1>2.3</h1>
            <p>slide 2.3</p>
            <p class="datetime"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-panel-section mb-slider">
        <div class="mb-panel active">
            <h1>3.1</h1>
            <p>slide 3.1</p>
            <p class="datetime"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-panel">
            <h1>3.2</h1>
            <p>slide 3.2</p>
            <p class="datetime"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-panel">
            <h1>3.3</h1>
            <p>slide 3.3</p>
            <p class="datetime"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the slides will vary in the number of items depending on how many notices there have been made.

I have the current CSS:

```css
.mb-panel-container {
    width: 100vw;
    margin-top: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
.mb-panel-section {
    width: calc( ( 100vw - 3px ) / 3 );
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
.mb-panel-section.mb-slider {
    height: calc( 100vh - (4em + 1.75em + 2em + 5em) );
}
.mb-panel-section .mb-panel {
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.mb-panel-section.mb-slider .mb-panel {
    padding: 5em 2em 3em;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
.mb-panel-container .mb-panel-section .mb-panel.active { opacity: 1; }
```

And the Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items = $('.mb-panel');
    var currentItem = items.filter('.active');
    window.setInterval( function(){
        var nextItem = currentItem.next();
        currentItem.removeClass('active');
        if ( nextItem.length ) {
            currentItem = nextItem.addClass('active');
        } else {
            // If you want it to loop around
            currentItem = items.first().addClass('active');
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```

However, while it cycles through the first panel indefinitely, the other two won't loop, but end on the final panel.

I'm not entirely sure where to alter the code, and not wanting to duplicate the JS code to for each panel section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for a solution later on, here is what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items       = $(".mb-panel"),
        currentItem = items.filter(".active");

    window.setInterval( function() {
        var nextItem = currentItem.next();
        currentItem.removeClass("active");

        if( nextItem.length ) {
            currentItem = nextItem.addClass("active");
        } else {
            currentItem = items.first().addClass("active");
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```

Essentially adds a class `active` to the next item in the div and then removes it, and adds it to the next one, so on. Makes it scalable indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is simpler than editing all those items. A pure CSS and JS solution, no JQuery, would go something like this.

```
const allSlides = document.querySelectorAll(".mb-slide");
const active = allSlides.filter(slide => slide.classList.contains("active"))[0];
const activeIndex = allSlides.findIndex(slide => slide === active);
const nextItem = allSlides[activeIndex + 1];
active.classList.remove("active");
nextItem.classList.add("active");
```

Meanwhile you'd start off the page with the first slide having a class of `.active` . In your CSS you could set something like:

```
.mb-slide{
 // all your other CSS
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
 }
.active{
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, I updated the question as there were multiple instance of the slides to be running, and updated your code to jQuery